# Use animation load bar with JS

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

**Edit:** See my answer below.

while waiting for `setTimeout` to runout, i thought it will be a good idea to add animation.

CSS:

```
.ws_addButton {border:1px black solid;border-radius:28px;}
.msg[data-status=toPublish] .ws_addButton {background-color:LightCoral;}
.msg[data-status=published] .ws_addButton {background-color:#7892c2; cursor:default;}

@keyframes loas_BG {
  from {background: linear-gradient(to right, Initial 0%, transparent 100%);}
  to {background: linear-gradient(to right, Initial 0%, transparent 0%);}
}
```

*I used `Initial` because i don't know the first color (blue or red)

And the JS that trigger it (need to run only once):

```
selectMSG.getElementsByClassName('ws_addButton')[0].style.animation = 'loas_BG '+ws_set_delay_basic+'s linear';
```

But it dosen't work (the animation dosen't start)), and I don't sure why.
tried to find information in google and here, but for now without luck.

`<s>any idea how to solve it?</s>`

**Edit:** See my answer below.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: oh, my false. it dosen't work and I don't sure why

Comment: @ItayAlon What "doesn't work"? Please be specific.

Comment: the animation: the colors all right, but the animation for transparent background dosen't show

Answer (score 0):

after a little more homework i tried this:

```js
var ws_set_delay_basic = 5;
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#ws_addButton'), ':before').style.animation = 'mymove '+ws_set_delay_basic+'s';
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* animation: mymove 5s; */
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from { width: 0; }
  to { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="ws_addButton"></div>
```

As you see, I tried to select a Pseudo-Element, but without success.
Without js, I can add animation directly to it (=Pseudo-Element), but then I do not have a dynamic time.

how can I add animation to Pseudo-Element correctly?

Comment: OK, solve it for now with creation of span: getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.animation = 'mymove '+delayTime+'s'; but I prefer the pseudo